# magento netsuite integration using SuitTalk crushes my page

Tags: web-services, magento, netsuite

I am trying to retrieve some data from netsuite to magento website. I am trying to use SuiteTalk. As the documentation in these link. http://www.netsuite.com/portal/developers/resources/suitetalk-sample-applications.shtml. I get it fetches the desired result in lunix terminal. But when i tried it to load it to page, the page crushed. The first time I tried to include it in block. and the second I used The observer. But both ways are not successful. does anyone have any idea?

The error log is as follows

```
 a:5:{i:0;s:33:"Webservice host must be specified";i:1;s:3914:"#0 /dir/magento_1.9/app/code/local/Etech/CustomerSupport/Block/PHPToolkit/NetSuiteService.php(132596): NSPHPClient->__construct(NULL, Array)
    #1 /dir/magento_1.9/app/code/local/Etech/CustomerSupport/Block/MyClass.php(12): NetSuiteService->__construct()
    #2 /mydir//magento_1.9/app/code/local/Etech/CustomerSupport/Block/MyBlock.php(14): MyClass->get_customer()
    #3 /mydir//magento_1.9/app/design/frontend/shopper/default/template/etech/index.phtml(9): Etech_CustomerSupport_Block_MyBlock->getCustomer()
    #4 /mydir//magento_1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
    #5 /mydir//magento_1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/shoppe...')
    #6 /mydir//magento_1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
    #7 /mydir//magento_1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
    #8 /mydir//magento_1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
    #9 /mydir//magento_1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
    #10 /mydir//magento_1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
    #11 /mydir//magento_1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
    #12 /mydir//magento_1.9/app/design/frontend/shopper/default/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(59): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
    #13 /mydir//magento_1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
    #14 /mydir//magento_1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/shoppe...')
    #15 /mydir//magento_1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
    #16 /mydir//magento_1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
    #17 /mydir//magento_1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
    #18 /mydir//magento_1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
    #19 /mydir//magento_1.9/app/code/local/Etech/CustomerSupport/controllers/IndexController.php(27): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
    #20 /mydir//magento_1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Etech_CustomerSupport_IndexController->indexAction()
    #21 /mydir//magento_1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
    #22 /mydir//magento_1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
    #23 /mydir//magento_1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
    #24 /mydir//magento_1.9/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #25 /mydir//magento_1.9/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
    #26 {main}";s:3:"url";s:5:"/mgt/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default”;}
```

NSConfig details

```
<?php
$nsendpoint = "2015_1";
$nshost = "https://webservices.na1.netsuite.com";

$nsemail = "*****@*****.com";
$nspassword = “********";
$nsrole = "3";
$nsaccount = “******";
?>
```

Comment: It is fixed by hardcoding the entire content of NSConfig.php to NSPHPClient.php inside the constructor NSPHPClient class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fixed by hardcoding the entire content of NSConfig.php to NSPHPClient.php inside the constructor NSPHPClient class.